# batch file to execute a command on all files in multiple directories

Tags: windows, command-line, for-loop, batch-file, batch-processing

I would like to make a batch file that runs this command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "C:\Users\digi_admin\TIFFs\
OLD DIRECTORY\*.tif" /ini="C:\Users\digi_admin\Documents\" /advancedbatch /tifc=4  
/convert="C:\Users\digi_admin\CompTIFs\Some Folder\NEW DIRECTORY\*.tif"
```

On all the files in several folders. All the files will be located in \TIFFs\ but will reside in several different sub-folders. (OLD DIRECTORY) Also I need to create the folder \NEW DIRECTORY\ (which will have the same name as OLD DIRECTORY) before the command is ran (is run?). Here is what I have so far:

```
FOR /D %d IN ("C:\Users\digi_admin\TIFFs\*.*") DO "C:\Program Files 
(x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" %d\*.tif /ini="C:\Users\digi_admin\Documents\" 
/advancedbatch /tifc=4 /convert="C:\Users\digi_admin\CompTIFs\Some Folder\%d\*.tif"
```

I have been trying it in command line so %d should be %%d. I am unfamiliar with DOS so I'm sure it is relatively simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET destroot=C:\Users\digi_admin\CompTIFs
FOR /D %%d IN ("%destroot%\*") DO (
MD "%destroot%\%%~nxd" 2>nul

"C:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "%%d\*.tif" /ini="C:\Users\digi_admin\Documents\" /advancedbatch /tifc=4 /convert="%destroot%\%%~nxd\*.tif"
)
```

Now - that's assuming the '/convert' is a destination filespec.

Notes:

- I've set the destination root into a variable - makes the typing
  easier
- the 2>nul suppresses the error message generated should the
  destination directory already exist
- %%~nxd means the Name and eXtension from %%d. In all probability, the
  extension won't exist - this is harmless

Comment: I will try that tomorrow. Looks like I wasn't even playing the same game.... Let alone in the ballpark.

Comment: I'd merely copied your ...i_view32... from your initial post and modified it. You appear to have executed the command from the prompt and thus you've used `%d` but within a batch file, you need to use `%%d` and I'd omitted to change it. Now fixed - I hope. The consequence would have been that Irfanview couldn't find the source files. I had no knowledge of Irfanview's `/convert` switch - what it was doing - but it appears that it specifies the destination FILE(s) to be created rather than the destination DIRECTORY. Hence `/convert="%destroot%\%%~nxd\*.tif"` would appear to be correct

Comment: BTW - if you add an `ECHO` keyword before the line `"C:\Program Files (x86)\...` then you'll see the PROPOSED Irfanview invocation rather than EXECUTING it. Lot easier (and fater) to fix `IF` there's something amiss...

Comment: It was exactly what I needed thank you. I marked your answer as accepted. Is there another way to show my appreciation? (I only have 3 reputation)