# How do I execute an exe file in multiple folders in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I have got a file ad.exe that operates on text files present in the same folder.
It is located in D:/.../bin. When executed, it read data from file 8000.txt and creates 98.txt. I have many folders containing 8000.txt in each of them. I want the exe file to act on every 8000.txt in each folder. All these 8000.txt files are located in multiple folders located in a single folder on my desktop.
I want to avoid copying the same file into each folder, and execute each of them one by one. I want to do all that work at once.
What do I do?

I have read
[batch file to execute a command on all files in multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351034/batch-file-to-execute-a-command-on-all-files-in-multiple-directories)
but could not understand it.

Comment: You need to add more details. How do you invoke it? Do you have to pass the list of text files on the command line?

Comment: I edited the the question. Mays be now it is a bit clear..

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is a `FOR loop` which DOS has in-line help accessed by using `For /?` and reading.  Open two `CMD` windows and use one for the help and the second to try commands.  TIP:  Use `ECHO` to only display text in DOS rather can running commands as a test.

The quick and easy way to do something such as this is to create a list of text files.  Use `dir /s /b *.txt >> c:\output.log`  this creates a file with a listing of every text file in all sub folders.

Next is the `FOR loop`

`FOR /f %a in (output.log) do echo %a`

FOR will open `output.log` and read every line.  Each line is represented by `%a` which is simple written to the console.  If the command was `do dir %a` the command would run `DIR` on every file in the `output.log`

Simply adjust to suit your needs and post back if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %f IN (`DIR /S /B 8000.txt`) DO (myprog.exe "%f")
```

If this is placed into a .bat or .cmd script, be sure to double the percent character on the filename variable.

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%f IN (`DIR /S /B 8000.txt`) DO (
    myprog.exe "%%f"
)
```